# offsetTop / getBoundingClientRect().top of the element with position: sticky

Tags: scroll, position, offset, sticky, getboundingclientrect

When element with `position: sticky` reach his offset (`top: 0`, for example) and stops on the screen, i can't get his `offsetTop` properly, it shows more than necessary. At the same time, I can't get `getBoundingClientRect().top`, because it shows `0`. Please take a look at this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lxud76ma/

When the element is sticky, it reserves its place in DOM, but the calculations are takes on its actual location.

So, how can I get coordinates of an element when it is sticky? Any ideas?

Comment: jsFiddle link no longer works.

Comment: @matharden really, thanx, i fixed the link with a problem.
Anyway, I found a solution in this question by temporary changing `position: sticky` to `position: static`: https://jsfiddle.net/Lk74do8u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i find an answer, but correct me if somebody know more properly way.

Before calculating need to change `position` of element from `sticky` to `static`. Get his coordinates and bring him back to `position: sticky`.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lk74do8u/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to calculate the `getBoundingClientRect` on the content/child of the sticky element.

```html
    <div class="sticky" id="sticky">
      <div id="stickyContent">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have updated your example:
https://jsfiddle.net/3962n0ov/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question just by curiosity .... but why we would need to get the position from the top of the page(offsetTop) since its always gonna be sticky to the top .... if its sticky to the top the position gonna be surely the **window.scrollY** position i tested it .... if its sticky to the left i dont really know the correct answer

Comment: Hello! You are right. But that my question was very specific to the situation.
I needed to know where the sticky element would be if it wasn't sticky. I needed that for animation based on scroll. So the answer was to temporary make him static during the calculations and than back him to sticky state.

Comment: sure that will work but here is another solution if you dont wanna use this one because it may interrupt your design for some miliseconds or more in low end devices .. the solution is to calculate the position of its previous sibling and add the height of the sibling +margin between them if tou wanna calculate from top or substract the height+margin of element if the sibling is next..The syntax is element.previousElementSibling to get the sibling

Comment: Sounds great too! I'll try it when I return to the project. Thank you.